# bulk importing magento had some kinds of limitation

Tags: magento, import, bulk

I am using magento (1.9.3) import function to upload new products with images together bulkly.

A. If there is more than two SKUs in CSV file (all fields listed below), import procedure will be stuck and can't be completed. For same data, if I keep only one SKU in one file, it can be imported properly.

B. And then, if I separate product description and images to two files, 10 SKUs can be imported in one time without images. But for image file part, it still has issue for two SKUs limitation.

C. And there is another limitation for image quantity. Image file for one SKU is limited to 9. If there are more than 9 images in CSV file for one SKU, import procedure will be stuck too.

I did check Magento manual and could not find information about those kinds of limitation.

Could anyone give me advice? Thanks.

Fields inside CSV file:

```
sku
_store
_attribute_set
_type
_category
_root_category
_product_websites
description
name
price
short_description
status
tax_class_id
url_key
url_path
visibility
weight
qty
is_in_stock
image
small_image
thumbnail
image_label
small_image_label
thumbnail_label
_media_image
_media_attribute_id
_media_is_disabled
_media_position
_media_lable
```

Comment: Sounds like a server configuration issue?  Or maybe a line ending issue? Which version of Magento and what's creating the CSV file?

Comment: @DraganAscii Thank you for your comment. I am using Magento 1.9.3 and CSV file is created from exported product list. All fields included in import file is shown above.

Comment: Problem solved: limitation is coming form PHP. Modified memory limitation and import procedure can work properly now. Thanks for everyone.